# Why doesn't Unity let me build my project with TextMeshPro after updating to Unity 2017.4.5?

Tags: unity

I have recently upgraded to Unity 2017.4.5. This required me to reimport TextMeshPro which I used previously in the project. Now I am trying to build (Android, Windows) and it is giving me hell a lot of errors, but I do not have any when I want to run the project. It is yelling about TMP, it does not find specific scripts. I tried to move around the runtime and the editor dll, reimporting all, googleing the error message, but it did not help.
Please see my errorlog: http://pasted.co/35185b3c.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem was the version of the TMP, I'd had . I had to delete the TextMesh Pro Unitypackage from my:

```
C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Asset Store-5.x\Unity Technologies\Unity EssentialsBeta Content
```

and then I reinstalled TMP from the Asset Store, and it works now.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029059/textmesh-pro-unity-plugin-stopped-working-after-updating-unity-to-5-6-beta) post might be helpful for someone else, that is where I found my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the TMP package ? It seems like unity is not finding any of the file corresponding to the asset. I know I had ussues too with TMP when I upgraded my unity version but it was solved after reinstalling unity as a whole (I formatted my computer for other reasons)

Comment: Yes, but it did not help...